# Is there a way to automatically position and fit a flextable object on a PowerPoint slide using RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

## The problem

When I generate a flextable object to be printed to a PowerPoint slide using RMarkdown, RMarkdown just sort of...throws the table on the slide.

````
```{r example}
tibble(
  COL_1 = seq(1, 25),
  COL_2 = seq(1, 25),
  COL_3 = seq(1, 25),
  COL_4 = seq(1, 25),
  COL_5 = seq(1, 25)
) |>
  qflextable() |>
  add_footer_row(values = "This is some example text just to highlight what gets lost in normal formatting.", colwidths = 5)
```
````

With the above code, I end up with something like this:
[image]

## What I want

Ideally, I'd like my table to be centered on the slide and formatted to fit, as in the below:
[image]

**Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get the desired result without manually editing the slide in PowerPoint?**

Note that [this question was previously posed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197071/adjusting-flextable-position-in-rmarkdown) but did not receive a workable answer.

Comment: There is an illustration in the doc about the question about centering: https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-powerpoint.html#center-an-element-with-fixed-size. The other question is about using the utility flextable::fit_to_width()

Comment: Thanks for the response, @DavidGohel . The solution shown appears geared towards generating slides in a standard R script. Can that approach be used in an RMarkdown chunk that outputs to a PowerPoint presentation?

Comment: Sorry, I replied too fast. Yes it is possible, but it requires some code, I have added an answer for R Markdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by using "officedown". But it requires some calculation. First know the slide dimensions (with `office::slide_size()`), then the flextable dimensions (with `flextable_dim()`) and finally compute the left and top positions that will be used by PowerPoint.

Flextable can be positioned in the slide with knitr chunk parameters `ft.left` and `ft.top`.

The following is illustrating the quick explanation.

````
---
output: 
  officedown::rpptx_document:
    reference_doc: template_demo.pptx
---

```{r include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(officedown)
library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

sl_size <- read_pptx("template_demo.pptx") %>% 
  add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>% 
  slide_size()

s_w <- sl_size$width 
s_h <- sl_size$height

ft <- flextable(head(iris)) %>% 
  fontsize(size = 18, part = "all") %>% 
  theme_vader() %>% 
  autofit()

ft_dim <- flextable_dim(ft)

left <- (s_w/2) - (ft_dim$widths/2)
top <- (s_h/2) - (ft_dim$heights/2)
```

```{r ft.left=left, ft.top=top}
ft
```
````

[image]